# Setting up proxy in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy

I would like to allow to use proxies on my chrome extension but no matter what user enters, ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES appears.
Here is my code for proxy connection:

```
var prxobj = JSON.parse(localStorage['proxy']);
ip = prxobj['proxyip'];
port = parseInt(prxobj['proxyport']);
var obj = {
    mode: 'fixed_servers',
    rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: 'https',
            host: ip,
            port: port
        },
        bypassList: ['']
    }
};
chrome['proxy']['settings']['set']({
    value: obj,
    scope: 'regular'
}, function() {})
```

Code for proxy auth:

```
chrome['webRequest']['onAuthRequired']['addListener'](function(first, second) {
    var objx= JSON.parse(localStorage['proxy']);
    first({
        authCredentials: {
            username: objx['proxyusername'],
            password: objx['proxypassword']
        }
    })
}, {urls: ['<all_urls>'] }, ['asyncBlocking']);
```

Comment: In general, [accessing properties of Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) is better written using dot notation (e.g. `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener`), rather than bracket notation (e.g. `chrome['webRequest']['onAuthRequired']['addListener']`) when the property name is static. There are times, however, where you need to use bracket notation and a string literal, due to the characters used in the property name not being permitted in a JavaScript identifier (e.g. a space).

Comment: I use them alternately. Any Idea how to solve my problem? @Makyen

Comment: It's not something I've worked on previously. Thus, I'd have to test. You haven't provided a complete [MCVE], so that would take more work than I'm wanting to put out at the moment. The following are a couple of comments describing what's actually required for debugging questions, and a bit about why it's helpful to have it in the question.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.